# Complex impedence between 2 terminals

Tags: complex-numbers

I have this problem to solve.

[image]

I have this so far. I am struggling with this so looking for some help please.

$$\frac{1}{5j}+\frac{1}{5+8.66j}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{-10j}=-\frac{j}{5}+\frac{5-8.66j}{5^2+8.66^2}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{j}{10}=a-bj$$

$$a:=\frac{5}{5+8.66}+\frac{1}{15},\,b=\frac{1}{5}+\frac{8.66}{5^2+8.66^2}-\frac{1}{10}=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{8.66}{5^2+8.66^2},$$

$$\frac{1}{a-bj}=\frac{a+bj}{a^2+b^2}.$$

I know i need a imaginary number for the x and real number for the y axis.

I an struggling because thier is more than 2 branches. I know:

$$ A + B = (4 + j1) + (2 + j3)
A + B = ( 4+2 ) + j(1+3)$$

So i added like this:

$$ j + 5 - 8.66j + 1 + j = -2.66j $$

But i guess this isn't correct?

This is for cartesian form.

Comment: You keep treating $j$ as $-1$ rather than a square root thereof.

Comment: I understand tat j = The square root of -1. But how a little confused on how to work it out. For example 5j. so is this 5 x the square root of -1?

Comment: Yes, viz. my answer.

Comment: Could you show me please? I still don't understand how to do this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't a clue what your last calculation there is doing. I don't know why you're adding those numbers together, nor have you added them correctly (their sum is $6-6.66j$).

Comment: I thought I was wrong. I will try again

Answer (score 1):

Impedances sum in series; admittances (reciprocals of impedances) sum in parallel. Thus the total admittance in $\Omega^{-1}$ is $$\frac{1}{5j}+\frac{1}{5+8.66j}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{-10j}=-\frac{j}{5}+\frac{5-8.66j}{5^2+8.66^2}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{j}{10}=a-bj$$with $$a:=\frac{5}{5+8.66}+\frac{1}{15},\,b=\frac{1}{5}+\frac{8.66}{5^2+8.66^2}-\frac{1}{10}=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{8.66}{5^2+8.66^2},$$while the total impedance in $\Omega$ is $$\frac{1}{a-bj}=\frac{a+bj}{a^2+b^2}.$$I'll leave arithmetic to you.

Comment: I am quite confused at this. I understand you have to take the reciprocal. Which I have done. My calculation is have got it: -0.099 = 0.564. This doesn't seem right though. Is this correct?

Comment: Double-check your $a$, your $b$, your $a^2+b^2$, your $\frac{a+bj}{a^2+b^2}$. The answer should be a real number, plus another real number times $j$.

Comment: I have double checked my answer, and came up with the same answer. Not to sure where i am going wrong???

Comment: @KyleAnderson Your "answer" states two real numbers are equal when they aren't. What it should look like is one complex number, with a real part and an imaginary part (and then, as per the question, you can convert it to polar form afterwards). You may need to review how complex numbers work.

Comment: I will review complex numbers and have another go. I understand that the imaginary number is one axis, and the real number is the other axis. It is just the arithmetic im not sure how to do.

Comment: Can anyone else help? I have watched a few youtube videos, but just don't fully understand enough to complete it.

Comment: Is a = 9.7266 and b = 75.442?

Comment: Also is $$a - bj = 129.99 - 2.66j$$???

Comment: @KyleAnderson Maybe you should also revise BODMAS, or PEMDAS or whatever calculator mnemonic you use.

Comment: Could you help me please @J.G. I have read and watched so many videos, i just don't understand how to work this out. I understand 80%. I just can't work this out.

Comment: @KyleAnderson Edit your question to include whatever calculations got you from the material in my answer to the values you mentioned in recent comments. Maybe then we'll know where you're slipping up.

Comment: I have edited my answer @J.G. So you can see how i got to one of the answers.